# Dynamically Show Product Promotions On Product Page Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I get a collection of the promotions that are tied to a particular product.

Comment: Hello check below link may be help you www.magikcommerce.com/magento-hello-extension

Comment: What promotions are you talking about? Catalog price rules?

Comment: Catalog and/or Cart price rules that involve the sku that I'm currently looking at. If theres a rule that says any product belonging to a particular category gets X dollars off and im on catalog_product_view_simple of a product within that category, I want the entity of the promotion to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is one of these two methods. Chose one which suits you better:

1. `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::getRulesFromProduct()`
2. `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::getRulesForProduct()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Magentos related products block for this.
You attach related products to a specific product in the admin panel.
These will then appear in the related product block which by default is in the right sidebar.

If it doesn't appear you can just add it to left sidebar, content or right sidebar by adding the following xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to find the Sales Rules that can be applied for any particular product till that product is added in the cart, cause Sales Rules depends on current shopping cart status like any Sales Rule only applied if subtoal > XXXX.

But you can get the Catalog Price Rule by using

```
Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::getRulesForProduct($date, $wId, $pId)

$date :- Current date
$wid  :- Website Id
$pid  :- Product Id
```